# IE9 CSS issue with before and after

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS bug in one of the templates I am using.

Here is the hosting link:

[Demo Link](http://bootstraphunter.com/themes/preview/smartadmin/1.4.1/ajaxversion/#ajax/dashboard.html)

You have to click on the cog icon (the gear icon on top right) then click on the "Menu on top" option.

This is happening in IE9, the menu dropdown appeared to be squeezed (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVijp.jpg). I cannot figure out how to fix this or what to change as I cannot inspect element properly for IE9. Does anyone know or can help me with this? Been stuck for a while on it and my users needs this menu to be working.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: looks fine to me in IE9

Comment: How did you test it on IE9? Did you use the convention IE11 or 10 browser and then configured it to act like IE9? That wont work, you need an actual IE9 browser - you can test this via browserstack.com